# More details from DLL load failure [python c++ extension]

Tags: python, c, plugins, python-c-extension

I'm working on compiling a C++/python library on windows, and running into some DLL hell. The C++ library consists of multiple DLLs that dynamically load one and other. There's also a swig-based python wrapper.

Currently, when importing the swigged python package, I get: `ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.`.

**How can I debug this in more detail**? For instance, can python be made to report *which* DLL it is that can't be loaded, or what search paths were attempted?

Comment: Have you tried **[pdb](https://docs.python.org/2/library/pdb.html#module-pdb)** or **[gdb](https://wiki.python.org/moin/DebuggingWithGdb)**? It is pretty useful in debugging, not sure about in Windows though

Comment: Would http://www.dependencywalker.com/ (on the DLL you're trying to import from Python) help?  (It wouldn't if too much runtime determined suff is going on, but it's worth a try).